# Remove duplicate names from Name column - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a Name column. I want remove duplicate names

```
Name

JOHN A SMITH JOHN A SMITH JOHN A SMITH
MARK TOM MARK TOM
MARY RUTH JONES MARY RUTH JONES
```

Desired output

```
Name

JOHN A SMITH
MARK TOM
MARY RUTH JONES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PQ go to menu Add column > custom column and past below function, replace column1 with the name of your column:

```
Text.Combine(List.Distinct(Text.Split([Column1]," "))," ")
```